# Python equivalent of SQL: SELECT w/ MAX() and GROUP BY

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by, max

I have data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'ID': [1,1,2,3,3,3,4],
    'SOME_NUM': [8,10,2,4,0,5,1]
} );

df
    ID    SOME_NUM
0   1     8
1   1     10
2   2     2
3   3     4
4   3     0
5   3     5
6   4     1
```

And I want to group by the ID column while retaining the maximum value of SOME_NUM as a separate column. This would be easy in SQL:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(SOME_NUM)
FROM DF
GROUP BY ID;
```

But I'm having trouble finding the equivalent Python code. Seems like this should be easy. Anyone have a solution?

Desired result:

```
    new_df
    ID    SOME_NUM
0   1     10
1   2     2
2   3     5
6   4     1
```

Comment: Please read [Comparison with SQL](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as how you are using Pandas... use the groupby functionality baked in

```
df.groupby("ID").max()
```

Comment: Can this be extended to multiple columns? I don't think I made my hypothetical as complicated as it needed to be. In actuality I have multiply columns and want one row each for ID with the MAX for SOME_NUM and OTHER_NUM and YET_ANOTHER_NUM, etc. I can edit the original post to reflect this unless it's a really simple extension. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Nevermind. I just tried this and it works on multiple columns too. That's all I needed. Thank you!